# Why can my domain user write to a folder without "Write" permissions for "Users"' group?

Tags: windows, permissions, active-directory

I've an ordinary domain user called `DKFOO` that is able to write in the `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Movile Device Support` folder after being prompted for its password.

As a domain administrator, I don't want to allow domain users to write in this directory.

The `Write` permission is not enabled for `Users`, so why can `DKFOO` write to this directory?

Are domain users included under `Users`? If not, why are permissions for domain users not listed for the folder?

[image]

[image]

icacls:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support> icacls "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support"
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support 

    NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(I)(F)
    NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(I)(CI)(IO)(F)
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
    BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
    BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
    CREATOR OWNER:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
    APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(I)(RX)
    APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
    APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES:(I)(RX)
    APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
```

Comment: Did you simply check who's in that group?

Comment: Yes, and DKFOO is not there. What are default permissions   (or group) in this case?

Comment: Well you asked about Domain Users, so did you check whenever that group is there? In addition it's unusual to get a prompt for credentials as a regular user. So did you you what permissions he actually has? Maybe some indirect permissions grant him administrative privileges on that machine?

Comment: Is the name of your domain `DK1B...`?  I asked this question because it almost looks like a local user account on a machine `DK1B`

Comment: Can you please provide the text version? Run `ICACLS "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Movile Device Support"`

Comment: @Ramhound - it is the name of the local computer, not the domain.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - can I use Sysinternal accesschk to do the same thing? If yes, what is the command?

Comment: What is your problem with `ICACLS`? You should have it in every Windows by default. ICACLS seems to be much more detailed.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - I've updated with `icacls` output. Now, where can I see the permissions for `Domain Users`? - I don't see any. So, I guess default permissions are used? What are they?

Comment: Domain Users are typically members of the local "Users" group of domain member machines, so the permissions that apply to the local "Users" group here will normally apply to domain users.  However, as has been mentioned, a normal user who is not an administrator would not be prompted for credentials unless the user is in fact an administrator.

Comment: @DawnBenton - the domain user is not a local administrator. The prompt is displayed, since elevated privileges are required to perform the action. Using `net localgroup Administrators`, `DKFOO` is not a member. What could be the issue?

Comment: Is this a true statement: a non-administrator user attempts to write to the protected directory, is prompted for adminstrative credentials to elevate, enters their NON-administrator credentials, and then the write is successful?

Comment: @DawnBenton - Indeed, this is what I can’t understand. The particular user is a standard domain user logged into the machine.

Comment: Domain users are not listed in ‘net user’ only in ‘net user /domain’.

Comment: However, domain users are listed in ‘net localgroup Users’.

Comment: I wonder if, since it's not an administrator, the credentials might be silently failing and the write is being redirected via UAC virtualization. Is there anything in %LocalAppData%\VirtualStore ?

Comment: @DawnBenton - I will check later. But, can you tell me this? Why are the group Domain Users not represented in icacls or the Security window? Are they getting default permissions for the folder? If so, what are they?

Comment: Because "domain users" is not on the access control list. However, since "Domain Users" is a member of the "Users" group, the permission entry for "Users" applies to them.

Comment: @DawnBenton - this is weird then, because they don’t have write permission. I will get back to you later on the VirtualStore.

Comment: Stupid question: Who is the owner of this folder?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - how can I check that?

Comment: `dir /q "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support"`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - I've checked the owner, it is SYSTEM. A screenshot is added to the question.

Comment: @DawnBenton - The folder is empty, I've just checked.

Comment: If it is not UAC file redirection (VirtualStore is empty), then go the the Effective Access tab and put the user ID and have it tell you exactly what kind of access the user has to that folder. If it says it has write access, the user must have administrator access somehow and check to see if the local administrators group contains a domain group that the user is a member of. If the effective Access tab shows only read, I can't think of anything else except a major bug (showstopper, don't ship)  in Windows. That's unlikely IMO, though.

Comment: @DawnBenton - Since "Domain Users" is member of "Users", I view the effective permissions for "Users". It says read-only, so I guess we are out of luck. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Just so you know, in that "Effective Access" tab, if you put the actual user name, it will show you the permissions that user has taking into account all of that user's group memberships, either direct or nested. If there's a difference between the user and the group in that Effective Access tab, then it's likely that user has admin rights through another group membership. Edit to add: definitely see if there's any domain group that the user is a member of  inside the local admin group.

Comment: @DawnBenton - when I try to search for specific domain user, it can’t find any. Only local users can be found when searching in effective tab, although “net user /domain” works just fine?